# Installing Ruby 2.0.0 using RVM with errors in configure

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I am currently running on Ruby 1.9.3p134 and trying to install Ruby 2.0.0 using RVM, however I keep running into the errors below. I am running on OSX 10.7.5:

> Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib
>   CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include
>   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195
>   --with-opt-dir=/opt/sm/pkg/active --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared' please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1369791751_configure.log There has
>   been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

The configure log as below:

> [2013-05-29 11:42:31] ./configure configure: WARNING: unrecognized
>   options: --without-tcl, --without-tk checking build system type...
>   x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2 checking host system type...
>   x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2 checking target system type...
>   x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2 checking whether the C compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p195': configure:
>   error: C compiler cannot create executables See`config.log' for more
>   details

Just couldn't get around this for days and I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update your RVM, it will either fix the problem or tell you what to do, run the following command and read all the outputs:

```
rvm get stable
```

Comment: This didn't work for me; the error was a strange argument being supplied to configure:  "configure --with-arch=-arch x86_64", whereas it should be "configure --with-arch=x86_64".

The problem was in .rvmrc.  If you have this problem, rename .rvmrc to something else and retry.