# Trouble installing ruby 1.9.3 because of a configuration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

This is my website: http://collegeanswerz.com. It was working fine about a week ago. Then I tried upgrading to Rails 4 (from Rails 3.2), and I screwed it up. I've been trying for the past week to get it back up, but haven't been successful.

I'm not sure how to word this because someone from [Rails Hotline](http://rails.pockethotline.com/) helped me, but I used git to go back to an earlier version of my code. A version of my code when my site was up and running.

I tried running `bundle install`, but it didn't work, because it said that my Gemfile specified Ruby 1.9.3, but I was using Ruby 2.0.0. The guy from Rails Hotline had me run some commands, and said he thinks that Ruby 1.9.3 was deleted from my computer. And there was something wrong with my RVM too I think, so he had me run `rvm implode`, and then reinstall it. I think I did that successfully.

Then I tried running `rvm install 1.9.3`. It didn't work because of some configuration error. See below:

```
Last login: Mon Jan 20 23:15:28 on ttys001
~ >>  cd collegeanswerz
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm implode
-bash: rvm: command not found
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm implode
-bash: rvm: command not found
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm -v
-bash: rvm: command not found
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm info
-bash: rvm: command not found
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm implode
-bash: rvm: command not found
~/collegeanswerz >>  curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    342      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   342
100 20511  100 20511    0     0  20831      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 20831
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz

Installing RVM to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/adamzerner/.bashrc /Users/adamzerner/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile /Users/adamzerner/.zprofile.
Installation of RVM in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# Adam Zerner,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io
  * It looks like some old stuff is laying around RVM, you can cleanup with: rvm cleanup all

~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm get head && rvm reload
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3-p484 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484'
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/adamzerner/.bashrc /Users/adamzerner/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/adamzerner/.bash_profile /Users/adamzerner/.zprofile.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/ is complete.

# Adam Zerner,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * It looks like some old stuff is laying around RVM, you can cleanup with: rvm cleanup all

  * No new notes to display.

RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3-p484 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484'
RVM reloaded!
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3-p484 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484'
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3-p484 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484'
RVM reloaded!
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm install 1.9.3
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3-p484 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484'
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p484.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p484, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9806k  100 9806k    0     0   679k      0  0:00:14  0:00:14 --:--:--  680k
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p484 to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484.
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #applying patch /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #configuring.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/1390278456_ruby-1.9.3-p484/configure.log
[2014-01-20 23:27:42] ./configure
current path: /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/Ghostscript/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/bin
command(6): ./configure --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

For quick reference, the main error is this:

```
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/1390278456_ruby-1.9.3-p484/configure.log
```

If someone could please help me fix this error, and get my site back up, I would really really appreciate it. I've been trying for days with no success. My site is a startup I'm trying to get going that does student reviews of colleges. I have 3 pilot schools where I'm paying students to answer questions, and the deadline to answer is February 1st. I need more answers but I can't get my site back up. Again, I would really appreciate some help (sorry for the ramble).

**Config.log file**

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Macintosh.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 13.0.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 2 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
2 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 199 tasks, 804 threads, 2 processors
Load average: 4.33, Mach factor: 0.34
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/libtool/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/automake/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin
PATH: /usr/local/heroku/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/Ghostscript/bin
PATH: /opt/ImageMagick/bin
PATH: /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2799: checking build system type
configure:2813: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
configure:2881: checking host system type
configure:2894: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
configure:2914: checking target system type
configure:2927: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
configure:3408: checking for C compiler version
configure:3417: /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3428: $? = 0
configure:3417: /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /Volumes/Media/Builds/gcc-5666.3/build/obj/src/configure --disable-checking --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++,fortran --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
configure:3428: $? = 0
configure:3417: /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 -V >&5
gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:3428: $? = 1
configure:3417: /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 -qversion >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
configure:3428: $? = 1
configure:3448: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3470: /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2    conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3474: $? = 1
configure:3512: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3517: error: in `/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484':
configure:3519: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_prog_CC=/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='ruby'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTDLDFLAGS=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
POSTLINK=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2013-11-22'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin13.0.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin13.0.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin13.0.0'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

**UPDATE: Ruby 1.9.3 installed, but `bundle install` doesn't work now**

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  bundle install
ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use 2.0.0` first.
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm use 1.9.3
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.


RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

~/collegeanswerz >>  bundle install
ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use 2.0.0` first.
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

**UPDATE: Clean up command didn't work**

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm cleanup all
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

Cleaning up rvm archives
Cleaning up rvm repos
Cleaning up rvm src
Cleaning up rvm log
Cleaning up rvm tmp
Cleaning up rvm gemsets
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/.autotest: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/design_rationale.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/History.txt: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/hoe/minitest.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/autorun.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/benchmark.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/hell.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/mock.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/pride.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/spec.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/Manifest.txt: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/Rakefile: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/README.txt: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/metametameta.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_benchmark.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_mock.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_spec.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_unit.rb: Operation not permitted
 - failed - /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/.autotest: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/design_rationale.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/History.txt: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/hoe/minitest.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/autorun.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/benchmark.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/hell.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/mock.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/pride.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/spec.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/Manifest.txt: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/Rakefile: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/README.txt: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/metametameta.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_benchmark.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_mock.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_spec.rb: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_unit.rb: Operation not permitted
 - failed - /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
Cleaning up rvm links
Cleanup failed for 2
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem "actionmailer", "~> 3.2.13"
gem "jquery-tablesorter", "~> 1.5.0"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-themes'
gem 'chart-js-rails'

ruby '1.9.3-p484'

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem "dynamic_form"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'asset_sync'
  gem 'fontello-rails'
  gem "jquery-smooth-scroll-rails", "~> 0.0.3"

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: I notice that I ran `rvm install 1.9.3` instead of `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484`. Well I just ran the latter, and it had the same issue.

Comment: please provide the `config.log`

Comment: do you have a line like `ruby '1.9.3'` in your `Gemfile` or have a `.ruby-version` file pointing to 1.9.3? If so just set the value back to your former `ruby version` to get your old setup up and running again

Comment: @majioa where do I find that? Is it a file?

Comment: Yes it is the config log file. I believe somewhere in the `/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484`...

Comment: Why not try `rvm get stable && rvm reload` instead of `rvm get head && rvm reload`? Because head is always keep updating you never know what breaks? I'm just guessing though. Just try with stable and then run: `rvm install 1.9.3`

Comment: @erndenson Yes, I have `ruby "1.9.3"` in my Gemfile. I don't see a .ruby-version file though.

Comment: when you set it to `ruby '1.9.2'` and restart your app - assuming you rolled back to `rails '3.2.x'` - you should get your app up running again. As I understood, this is the first goal to achieve asap.

Comment: @erndenson I set it to 1.9.3 in my Gemfile, not 1.9.2. I think the problem is that 1.9.3 isn't installed, because when I installed 2.0.0, I must have deleted it.

Comment: under which ruby version did your app run, before you switched to `rails 4`? Use this version, to "heal" your app, before fixing the 1.9.3 config problem

Comment: @Surya I just followed the directions from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2#sec-install_ruby because that's what I used initially. Anyway, I tried what you said, and it didn't work for the same reason.

Comment: @erndenson I used ruby 1.9.3 before I switched to rails 4. I'm trying to get back to this version, but the issue is that I can't, and I think the config problem is preventing me from doing so.

Comment: ok - understood. Then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139138/how-can-i-install-ruby-1-9-3-in-mac-os-x-lion) for your installation problem. Hope that will help

Comment: @erndenson Seems like a good idea. But I'm always hesitant to just follow that sort of stuff. What if that person's app is different from mine, and running it that way screws something else up? I suspect that following these random answers is how my problems originate.

Comment: which version of Xcode are you running under? It seems your `lcrt1.10.6.o` library isn't found. Depending on your Xcode version i might be of little help

Comment: Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: Hmm, sorry, no help from here :( But in your position, i would try to use the `--with-gcc=clang`-option on `rvm install '1.9.3'` and see if this will help

Comment: yes, i think you can't break anything with that

Comment: hope, you'll get it up and running soon!

Comment: Things that jump out at me are this message: `It looks like some old stuff is laying around RVM, you can cleanup with: rvm cleanup all`

and these:

`configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk`

`configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Based on those messages and the comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804284/installing-ruby-2-0-0-using-rvm-with-errors-in-configure), I'd say you have some leftover configuration. If that cleanup command doesn't help, you can try what that other guy said and rename your `.rvmrc` to see if that helps.

Comment: @erndenson `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang ` worked, but it lead to a new problem. It says `ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use 2.0.0` first.` when I run `bundle install`. I then tried `rvm use 1.9.3`, but that didn't work. Any thoughts? (I posed the output as an update to the question).

Comment: @9nonnatus I just tried the `rvm cleanup all` command, and it didn't work. See the update to my question. I'm not sure what you mean about renaming `.rvmrc`.

Comment: great, at least one step worked... what rubies do you get listed when running `rvm list`? It should list at least one with version number 1.9.3 (most propably the 1.9.3-p448). Then run `rvm use 1.9.3-p448`.  
I will provide my suggestions as answer as well.

Comment: rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

Comment: rvm use 1.9.3-p448
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.


`RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.`

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example

Comment: please update your Gemfile with the `rvm '1.9.3-p484'` line and make sure, you're in the login shell (to change to it, use `/bin/bash --login`). After that your rvm commands should work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First goal should be to get the app back up running.
Therefore I would suggest to reset your app's configuration to the last working stand.
If this is not possible, please install ruby using rvm with the *--with-gg=clang*-option like this:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Then use the installed ruby version by listing all installed rubies (running `rvm list`) and choosing the 1.9.3 version provided (e.g. 1.9.3-p448) with the following command:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.3-p484
```

Please update your Gemfile with the `ruby '1.9.3-p484'` line and make sure, you're in the login shell (to change to it, use `/bin/bash --login`). After that your rvm commands should work again.

Comment: I replaced `ruby "1.9.3"` with `rvm '1.9.3-p484` in my Gemfile.

Comment: ~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm use 1.9.3-p448

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

~/collegeanswerz >>

Comment: What do you mean by the login shell? How do I get there?

Comment: open `Terminal`.app, and enter the following command `/bin/bash --login` - this sets e.g. your PATH-variable from ~/.bash_profile, where  some rvm-config is taking place

Comment: `~/collegeanswerz >>`  /bin/bash --login
`~/collegeanswerz >>`  rvm use 1.9.3-p448
ruby-1.9.3-p448 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448'
`~/collegeanswerz >>`  rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

~/collegeanswerz >>

Comment: you have misspelled the patch-version. To use and set the default ruby, run the command `rvm --default use 1.9.3-p484`

Comment: ~/collegeanswerz >>  rvm --default use 1.9.3-p484
Using /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484

Comment: ~/collegeanswerz >>  bundle install
Gemfile syntax error:
 gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
        ^

Comment: ok, now you have your rvm default ruby set to 1.9.3. The pg-Error is what @HyunsooChoi described in his comment - do `bundle install --without production`

Comment: ~/collegeanswerz >>  bundle install --without production
Gemfile syntax error:
 gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

Comment: maybe this is relevant though - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-heroku_setup

Comment: Gemfile added to question.

Comment: ahh I messed up. now I fixed it - `rvm '1.9.3-p484'`. now I've got a new error though: `collegeanswerz >>  bundle install --without production
Undefined local variable or method `rvm' for Gemfile
        from /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Gemfile:11`

Comment: the line must run like this: `ruby '1.9.3-p484'` - this was my error (updated in answer)

Comment: ok, now it says `~/collegeanswerz >>  bundle install --without production
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3-p484`

Comment: so then try it without the patch `ruby '1.9.3'` - there is something really strange going on here :-/

Comment: oh I know. Rails doesn't like me :)

Comment: `bundle install --without production` seems to be working now though

Comment: finally! I'd appreciate, when you accept and upvote my answer :D

Comment: absolutely! i actually don't have enough reputation to upvote (just gave away a bounty), but i'll definitely select it! I'm just precompiling and running git add, git commit, and git push now. That stuff should all work though.

Comment: thx - is your app running again? I hope, you'll soon get it up again. And promise me, to check your local ruby-setup next time **before** you deploy to your production system :D

Comment: what does that mean? sorry, a lot of this stuff went over my head.

Comment: I don't know yet, how it could come to this worst-case-scenario, where you could neither step forward (rails 4 and ruby 2) nor backward (rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3). I think you should get more familiar with rvm and its features. I did not want to irritate you.

Comment: definitely. i've learned my lesson to be careful messing with things I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have `apple-gcc42` installed in `homebrew` on OSX 10.9, I guess you have updated your system and it's a leftover from previous OSX version, you should uninstall this package and rvm would install GCC 4.6 then and it all would have worked.

Answer (score -1):

I think the main issue is this:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

You need to provide us with the config file however, I think if you put this command:

```
sudo apt-get install clang && rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

It should solve the issue.

Comment: Which config file would you like? Or should I just run those commands? Note that `rvm install 1.9.3` recently just worked, but now `bundle install` isn't working.

Comment: Wait, so you were able to install Ruby 1.9.3? Okay, what errors are you getting upon bundle install? I'm assuming it has to do with the postgres gem file. Try `bundle install --without production`

Comment: See the first update to my question with the output for what happens when I ran `bundle install`. Do you still think I should try `bundle install --without production`?

Comment: I think the first solution would work. Your log isn't showing any pg errors. Funny how rvm implode couldn't get the job done. So I really think it has to do with 'gcc'. So try the first solution.

Comment: It wasn't me. I can't even vote (need 15 reputation).